# URL redirect[dynamic]

Tags: url, redirect, url-rewriting

Initially my URL for user posts was
`localhost/ad?id=1`

But then I added another column in my table called `post_slug` which is generated from the post title
so it shows like this `localhost/ad?slug=my_post_title` and if the slug is already used I just add a random number or letter at the end like `_1` `_e` but if users edit their post I want the slug to change to the new title but that will make the old URL go to 404

I tried looking on google but can't find anything relevant to my Q i want the old url to redirect to the new one.

Comment: You can add a column with 'original_slug' or something and that field is filled with the first initial slug. If someone changes the slug, the 'slug' field changes, but 'original_slug' keeps it's value. Now you can write a Middleware or something to check if the slug is set, if so, redirect `original_slug` to `slug`

Comment: nice solution I will keep it in mind and if there are no other answers i will mark your comment as the solution

Comment: What programming language are you using?   What web server are you using?  What type of database are you using?  Please [edit] your question to add details.  You should also have a [mcve] that shows what you are currently doing and how it fails in your new situation.